# 仮想環境を有効化においてのsourceコマンドのNotFoundエラーの解決法

Tags: python, python3, python-venv

```
python -m venv <仮想空間名>
```

で仮想空間を作り

```
source <仮想空間名>/bin/activate
```

と打ち有効にしようとすると`source`コマンドがNotFoundになってしまうんですがどうしたらいいでしょうか。
わかる方いたら是非教えてください。

Comment: 動作環境に依存する可能性がありそうです。[\[Ubuntu\]\[Shell\]Ubuntuの/bin/shでsourceコマンドが効かない件](https://blog.aoshiman.org/entry/112/), [source: not found in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32686520/9014308), [Getting a 'source: not found' error when using source in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670191/9014308), [source .venv/bin/activate - ends in error /bin/sh: 8: source: not found #12968](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12968), [Issue with virtualenv - cannot activate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921188/9014308) OS, Shell, IDE, エディタとかその辺の情報を追記してみては？

Answer (score 1):

dash（最近の Ubuntu の `/bin/sh` で使われているシェル）などのシェルでは `source` コマンドが存在しません。代わりに `.` コマンドを使ってください。あるいは、dash を使わずに bash や zsh を使ってください。

また、もし Windows 環境をお使いなのであればコマンドが異なります。https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html にプラットフォームごとの一覧表があるので参考にしてください。